# How to take output from iterating, store that in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, python-newspaper

So I have this script (running Python 3.5) using Google API and Newspaper.  It searches google for articles that have to do with sleep. And then using Newspaper, I iterate over those URLS. And all I'm asking Newspaper to do is return a list of keywords of that article, which I call by writing `article.keywords` .

```
for url in google.search('sleep', num=2, stop=1):
    article = Article(url)      
    article.download() 
    article.parse()
    article.nlp()     
    print(article.keywords)
```

The keywords that are returned (for a given article) look like this:

```
['education', 'nights', 'start', 'pill', 'supplement', 'research', 'national', 'sleep', 'sleeping', 'trouble', 'using', 'taking']
```

**But I want to create a dictionary full of ALL of the keywords for all the results: That is, the keywords for each article that is being iterated over. How would I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the dictionary key should be an article url:

```
keywords = {}
for url in google.search('sleep', num=2, stop=1):
    article = Article(url)      
    article.download() 
    article.parse()
    article.nlp()  

    keywords[url] = article.keywords

print(keywords)
```

Or, if you want to have a list of all the keywords from all the articles:

```
keywords = []
for url in google.search('sleep', num=2, stop=1):
    article = Article(url)      
    article.download() 
    article.parse()
    article.nlp()  

    keywords += article.keywords

print(keywords)
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent keywords being inserted multiple times (almost same as another answer)

```
keywords = []
for url in google.search('sleep', num=2, stop=1):
  article = Article(url)      
  article.download() 
  article.parse()
  article.nlp()
  for kw in article.keywords:
    if kw not in keywords:
      keywords.append( kw )
```

Or better yet, use a `set` instead of a `list`.

Comment: What's the benefit of a set over a list?

Comment: With the set, you do not have to check if the element is already present.  You can call the `add()` method with the same element multiple times.  The disadvantage is the the order of the elements will be random (i.e. not in the order the elements were added), unlike a list.